# Drupal 7 URL redirection - make it shorter according to pattern

Tags: url, redirect, design-patterns, drupal, drupal-7

I have a problem with my Drupal 7 site. I want to redirect all URLs matching pattern "catalog/something-0" to "catalog/something". I haven't found any suitable module yet.

I have tried Page Manager Redirect, Taxonomy redirect, Match redirect. Maybe I'm using them wrong.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `hook_preprocess_page()` in `template.php` file, and check for current path: e.g.:

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(current_path() == 'catalog/something-0') {
    drupal_goto('catalog/something');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this will be helpful. I need it to be more universal, not just for one particular URL. Word "Something" is replacement for many other words. It is something like *(star) in regular expression.

Comment: @matusm 1. `current_path() == 'URL'` is just an example, you don't need to use it. 2. I can't say there will be any universal way to achieve this.. 3. There are multiple ways to check for URL pattern, for ex. `arg()` function, `$_GET['q']` and `explode()`, and so on.. but logic will be similar..

Comment: I actually used another function to match the desired pattern, but the  whole idea came from this post. Thank you.